# Representing the strings we use in programming in math notation

Tags: string, math, notation

*Now I'm a programmer who's recently discovered how bad he is when it comes to mathematics and decided to focus a bit on it from that point forward, so **I apologize if my question insults your intelligence**.*

In mathematics, is there the concept of strings that is used in programming?  i.e. a permutation of characters.

As an example, say I wanted to translate the following into mathematical notation:

```
let s be a string of n number of characters.
```

Reason being I would want to use that representation in find other things about string `s`, such as its length: `len(s)`.

How do you formally represent such a thing in mathematics?

---

Talking more practically, so to speak, let's say I wanted to mathematically explain such a function:

```
fitness(s,n) = 1 / |n - len(s)|
```

Or written in more "programming-friendly" sort of way:

```
fitness(s,n) = 1 / abs(n - len(s))
```

*I used this function to explain how a fitness function for a given GA works; the question was about finding strings with 5 characters, and I needed the solutions to be sorted in ascending order according to their fitness score, given by the above function.*

So my question is, **how do you represent the above pseudo-code in mathematical notation?**

Comment: Two quick comments. First, if s is a string of n characters, then isn't len(s) by definition n? I am having trouble understanding the denominator, because it seems like n = len(s). Second, I looked at our sister site, Mathematics, and did a query on length with http://math.stackexchange.com/search?page=2&tab=relevance&q=length . In graph theory (which seems to be related to your question), they just use a letter for length, as in http://math.stackexchange.com/q/9293/5220.

Comment: No, `n` is not `len(s)`.  `n` is the target for my 'optimal' solutions and `len(s)` is just the number of characters for the given chromosome.

Comment: Yes they use `n` but I don't need to represent *any* length; I wanted to know a way on how to represent a string's length specifically and the notation involved.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the notation of language theory, which is used to discuss things like regular languages, context free grammars, compiler theory, etc. A quick overview:

- A set of characters is known as an **alphabet**. You could write: "Let *A* be the ASCII alphabet, a set containing the 128 ASCII characters."
- A **string** is a sequence of characters. ε is the empty string.
- A set of strings is formally known as a **language**. A common statement is, "Let *s* ∈ *L* be a string in language *L*."
- Concatenating alphabets produces sets of strings (languages). *A* represents all 1-character strings, *A**A*, also written *A*<sup>2</sup>, is the set of all two character strings. *A*<sup>0</sup> is the set of all zero-length strings and is precisely *A*<sup>0</sup> = {ε}. (It contains exactly one string, the empty string.)
- *A*<sup>*</sup> is special notation and represents the set of all strings over the alphabet *A*, of any length. That is, *A*<sup>*</sup> = *A*<sup>0</sup> ∪ *A*<sup>1</sup> ∪ *A*<sup>2</sup> ∪ *A*<sup>3</sup> ... . You may recognize this notation from regular expressions.
- For length use absolute value bars. The length of a string *s* is |*s*|.

So for your statement:

> let s be a string of n number of characters.

You could write:

> Let *A* be a set of characters and *s* ∈ *A*<sup>*n*</sup> be a string of *n* characters. The length of *s* is |*s*| = *n*.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, when the absolute value bars are used in the context of a string, they represent the length of the string?

Comment: +1 for steering OP toward language theory and lovely notation.

Comment: Aha, I think this is answer I was searching for...brilliant stuff for me to research more about.  Thanks a lot John and I hope I didn't insult your intelligence or anyone else's `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, you have explained `fitness(s, n)` just fine as long as `len(s)` is well-defined.

In CS texts, a string *s* over a set *S* is defined as a finite ordered list of elements of *S* and its length is often written as *|s|* - but this is only notation, and doesn't change the (mathematical) meaning behind your definition of `fitness`, which is pretty clear just how you've written it.